# registering OPC-UA Node server to LDS

Tags: node-opcua

hello i'm trying to register my OPC-UA server to a local run (for now) local discovery server. So when i run my server whit `registerServerMethod` set to lds i get this error :

```
RegisterServer to the LDS  has failed during secure connection  => please check that you server certificate is trusted by the LDS. err: The connection has been rejected by server,
Please check that client certificate is trusted by server.
Err = (connect EINVAL 0.0.14.186:4840 - Local (0.0.0.0:0))
```

so when i check the rejected folder of the LDS at (opt/opcfoundation/ualds/pki/rejected/certs) no certificates have been placed there.

i've tried several different certs, i've tied placing a copy of the cert in the trusted folder but nothing has worked so far. am i doing something wrong om the LDS ore is there something wrong whit my server code:

```
/*global require,setInterval,console */
const opcua = require("node-opcua");
const { SecurityPolicy, OPCUACertificateManager } = require("node-opcua");

// Let's create an instance of OPCUAServer
const server = new opcua.OPCUAServer({
    port: 4354, // the port of the listening socket of the server
    resourcePath: "/UA/testserver1", // this path will be added to the endpoint resource name
    buildInfo: {
        productName: "testserver",
        buildNumber: "0001",
        buildDate: new Date(2020, 7, 9)
    },
    //certificate and key
    certificateFile: "testcert2.pem",
    privateKeyFile: "testkey2.pem",
    //certificate manager
    serverCertificateManager: new OPCUACertificateManager({
        automaticallyAcceptUnknownCertificate: true,
        rootFolder: "./certs",
    }),
    //security policies
    securityPolicies: [SecurityPolicy.Basic256, SecurityPolicy.None],
    securityModes: [opcua.MessageSecurityMode.SignAndEncrypt, opcua.MessageSecurityMode.None],
    // setup LDS conncetion
    registerServerMethod: 3, // regsiterservermethod 3 = LDS
    discoveryServerEndpointUrl: "opc.tcp://localhost:4840",
});

function post_initialize() {
    console.log("initialized");
    function construct_my_address_space(server) {

        const addressSpace = server.engine.addressSpace;
        const namespace = addressSpace.getOwnNamespace();

        // declare a new object
        const device = namespace.addObject({
            organizedBy: addressSpace.rootFolder.objects,
            browseName: "MyDevice"
        });

        // add some variables
        // add a variable named MyVariable1 to the newly created folder "MyDevice"
        let variable1 = 1;

        // emulate variable1 changing every 500 ms
        setInterval(function () { variable1 += 1; }, 500);

        namespace.addVariable({
            componentOf: device,
            browseName: "MyVariable1",
            dataType: "Double",
            value: {
                get: function () {
                    return new opcua.Variant({ dataType: opcua.DataType.Double, value: variable1 });
                }
            }
        });

        // add a variable named MyVariable2 to the newly created folder "MyDevice"
        let variable2 = 10.0;

        namespace.addVariable({
            componentOf: device,
            nodeId: "ns=1;b=1020FFAA", // some opaque NodeId in namespace 4
            browseName: "MyVariable2",
            dataType: "Double",
            value: {
                get: function () {
                    return new opcua.Variant({ dataType: opcua.DataType.Double, value: variable2 });
                },
                set: function (variant) {
                    variable2 = parseFloat(variant.value);
                    return opcua.StatusCodes.Good;
                }
            }
        });

        const os = require("os");
        /**
         * returns the percentage of free memory on the running machine
         * @return {double}
         */

        function available_memory() {
            // var value = process.memoryUsage().heapUsed / 1000000;
            const percentageMemUsed = os.freemem() / os.totalmem() * 100.0;
            return percentageMemUsed;
        }

        namespace.addVariable({
            componentOf: device,
            nodeId: "s=free_memory", // a string nodeID
            browseName: "FreeMemory",
            dataType: "Double",
            value: {
                get: function () { return new opcua.Variant({ dataType: opcua.DataType.Double, value: available_memory() }); }
            }
        });
    }

    construct_my_address_space(server);

    server.start(function () {
        console.log("Server is now listening ... ( press CTRL+C to stop)");
        console.log("port ", server.endpoints[0].port);
        const endpointUrl = server.endpoints[0].endpointDescriptions()[0].endpointUrl;
        console.log(" the primary server endpoint url is ", endpointUrl);
    });
}


server.initialize(post_initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem i had was due to the hostname of my PC being a number, this caused a timeout and so the certificates weren't being send.

the solution was simple, change the hostname of my pc to something that starts whit a letter.

Answer (score 0):

In order to register to the Local Discover Server (LDS), a server needs to establish a secure connection.
A secure connection implies that the server and the LDS exchange their certificates and verify them.

Whereas some Local Discover Servers may be configured to automatically accept newly encountered certificates, some will perform a strict check and enforce that your server certificate is trusted.

You need to refer to your LDS documentation to check how you can add your server certificate to the trusted list of your LDS.

Certificate could be self-signed or provided by a Certification Authority. In this case, the certificate of the CA will also have to be added to the trusted issuer certificate list.

[added]

if you want, you can run a LDS (based on node-opcua) as a docker container:

```
 docker run -it -p 4840:4840 -v /tmp/lds-config:/root/.config -e HOSTNAME=`hostname` sterfive/lds:latest  -
```